# Shape analysis with fixed location and rotation

Tags: r, statistical-significance, biostatistics

I'm currently using a dataset of leaf scans to determine shape differences within the plant. Normal shape analysis removes influential factors such as location, rotation and scale to determine the "true shape" of the object. However, as a leaf is attached at a certain point, the factors rotation and location (e.g. one leaf may bulge more to the left) must remain within the analysis.

Therefore I've currently normalised the data to removed the scale influence and extracted sets a set of contour coordinates as landmark points.

I'm working with the package "shapes" and its function "testmeanshapes" in R and for some reason it always gives a terribly low p value:

test one: left oriented leaves vs right oriented leaves, reasonably large sample size (James p value = Goodall = Hotelling 0.000999)
[image: left vs right]

test two: rank 4 within the plant vs rank 8, small sample sizes (+/- 10, all p-values still at 0.000999)
[image: rank 4 vs rank 8]

At least visually, I believe there should be a larger uncertainty (and thus a higher p value) in the second test. Am I doing something very wrong here? Should I not be using contourpoints straight away or do I need to select different ones (such as those with the highest curvature for example)? Or is this package not doing what I think it is doing.

Note: When I randomly select leaves from my dataset and compare then I do get p values ranging from 0.25 to 0.8 so there may as well be significant differences in test 2, but I do not believe them to be so large with such a small sample size.

Comment: Although I am unfamiliar with `testmeanshapes`, I would bet it is bootstrapping the p-value and you have used a default of $1/0.000999 - 1 = 1000$ iterations.  Would this be correct?

Comment: Your assumption is correct. I ran the second test with 10000 resamples and it gave p.values of 9.999e-5, again to it's limit. Am I to assume these are simply extremely significant differences? They don't seem like it